# How to send a message from a C++ class to Objective-C ViewController?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I want to send a message including two parameters from a C++ class(.cpp file) to a Object-C ViewController(.m file), how can I do that?

Comment: You need to use Objective-C++ (an ".mm" file) instead of C++.

Answer (score 0):

As molbdnilo commented, change your C++ implementation file to extension .mm, making Xcode build it as Objective-C++. While you're at it, make the view controller implementation file .mm too. That way you can use both C++ and Objective-C types and syntax in both. You can either make an Objective-C method call from a C++ function, or handle a C/++ function in the view controller implementation module (but not the Obj-c class itself):

Try: 1. You can include Objective-C method syntax (square brackets and all) inside any C++ function implementations in a .mm file. Convert the params to C primitive types or Obj-C class instances to pass them.

Or: 2.  Make your view controller implementation file a .mm, and write a global C or C++ function in it that you can declare extern in your C++ file and call from there.  This removes the need to pass the view controller pointer to the C++ module. What I usually do here is keep a static pointer in the VC implementation file for the global function to access the view controller. Of course, that only gets you one instance. For multiple instances of the controller, you'll need another approach, such as #1.